# Can I use unarmed attacks to deliver touch attacks?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, unarmed-combat, touch-attacks

I know you can use unarmed strikes to deliver spells that need a touch attack.

However, is it also possible use unarmed strikes with spells that allow for several touch attacks, like Darkfire (SP, p59)?

> you can strike opponents with a melee touch attack, dealing 1d6 points of damage per 2 caster levels

So could a 11th level Monk with 5 levels of Cleric cast this spell and deliver 4 times this damage using Flurry of Blows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, you can

On [Holding the Charge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm), it says:

> If you don’t discharge the spell in the round when you cast the spell, you can hold the discharge of the spell (hold the charge) indefinitely. You can continue to make touch attacks round after round. You can touch one friend as a standard action or up to six friends as a full-round action. If you touch anything or anyone while holding a charge, even unintentionally, the spell discharges. If you cast another spell, the touch spell dissipates.
>
> Alternatively, **you may make a normal unarmed attack** (or an attack with a natural weapon) while holding a charge. In this case, you aren’t considered armed and you provoke attacks of opportunity as normal for the attack. (If your unarmed attack or natural weapon attack doesn’t provoke attacks of opportunity, neither does this attack.) If the attack hits, **you deal normal damage for your unarmed attack or natural weapon and the spell discharges**. If the attack misses, you are still holding the charge.

This means that instead of trying to touch your target with a standard action, you could use a full-round action (such as *Flurry of Blows* or a *Full Attack*) and attempt to deliver a held charge on each of your unarmed attacks. Keeping in mind that each attack will provoke attacks of opportunity unless you have the proper abilities to prevent those (like *Improved Unarmed Strike* or similar).

The wording on [Darkfire](https://dnd.arkalseif.info/dndtools/spells/spell-compendium--86/darkfire--4330/) is very similar to [Chill Touch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/chillTouch.htm), or even [Produce Flame](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/produceFlame.htm), which are common spells to use like this.

> **Darkfire**
>
> Beginning the following round, you can strike opponents with a melee touch attack, dealing 1d6 points of damage per 2 caster levels (maximum 5d6. Alternatively, you can hurl the flames up to 120 feet as a thrown weapon. When doing so, you make a ranged touch attack (with no range penalty) and deal the same damage as with the melee attack. No sooner do you hurl the flames than a new set appears in your hand.
>
> **Produce Flame**
>
> You can strike an opponent with a melee touch attack, dealing fire damage equal to 1d6 +1 point per caster level (maximum +5). Alternatively, you can hurl the flames up to 120 feet as a thrown weapon. When doing so, you attack with a ranged touch attack (with no range penalty) and deal the same damage as with the melee attack. No sooner do you hurl the flames than a new set appears in your hand.

Comment: but I am not "holding a charge", I thought it is only applicable for the first time it takes effect.

Comment: Strictly raw this is only available *If you don’t discharge the spell in the round when you cast the spell*, but also raw is this *Some touch spells allow you to touch multiple targets. ..., but all targets of the spell must be touched in the same round that you finish casting the spell.* One could reasonably argue that the specific spell descriptions may override both default behaviors, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: Im not gonna discuss raw on this, we have years of FAQs and erratas, and they are all equally bad.